# How to change keyboard button "Return" to "Search" for input in a UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, search, input, uiwebview

I have this simple HTML file that is to be displayed in a UIWebView.

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>
  <input name='search' type='search' placeholder="Input type is search" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the screenshot when I clicked the input box.

[image]

How to change the Return button to 'Search' like Google page does?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a simple solution. Just wrap the input with form tag so the HTML looks like this.

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>
  <form>
    <input name='search' type='search' placeholder="Input type is search" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And now the keyboard looks like

[image]

Comment: Do you know what the solution is for a textarea?

Comment: Is there any way, how to change the label of the "Search" button? For example - we have only suggestions by typing - there is no way how to "search". By pressing "Search" you go to the first suggestion item, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the reference: [Text Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) and I can see that the type search isn't an option, so I think that Safari handle that with a different way. Maybe with a custom inputview. Take a look in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961369/how-the-default-keyboard-comes-up-when-user-taps-in-uiwebview/20037193#20037193) to do that.

Answer (score -3):

You have to select the textfield & in identity inspector you select search shown in pic below :

[image]

Comment: Please check that he is using a WebView not a simple UITextView or UITextFIeld.