# Changing the keyboard return key in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have the following page I'm displaying in WkWebView

```
<html>
  <textarea name='message' placeholder='Type your message here'/>
</html>
```

And when entering text to this field, the keyboard displays a normal "Return" key.

I would like to change the label of the return key to "Send" just for this field.

Is that possible in WKWebView?

I'm aware of this answer: [How to change keyboard button "Return" to "Search" for input in a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320696/how-to-change-keyboard-button-return-to-search-for-input-in-a-uiwebview)
But the proposed solution only works in UIWebView.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who is still looking for the answer, we have html `enterkeyhint` property nowadays: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/enterkeyhint).

```html
<input id="send" enterkeyhint="send" />

<!— or —>

<textarea enterkeyhint="send"></textarea>
```

Most of the `enterkeyhint` values (enter/done/go/next/<s>previous</s>/search/send) have their iOS [UIReturnKeyType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uireturnkeytype) counterparts, and the return key changes to the corresponding appearance.

[image: Send Key Example]