# ios8 using custom keyboard in container app

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

Is it possible to use the custom keyboard from within the app container without adding the keyboard to general settings keyboards?

I would like my app to offer a custom keyboard but does not need to be enabled across all apps if not enabled in general settings. However it should be available from the container app itself at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `inputView` property of `UITextField` and `UITextView` and show the keyboard yourself. If you need to use your custom keyboard from a web view there are some instructions here: [How the default keyboard comes up when user taps in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961369/how-the-default-keyboard-comes-up-when-user-taps-in-uiwebview)