# Replace inputAccessoryView of keyboard in UIWebView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, keyboard, inputaccessoryview

I've been looking for days for a simple answer but I cannot seem to find it.

I want to find and replace the inputAccessoryView of keyboard attached to my  UIWebView if the accessory view exists on the keyboard.  I want to replace it so I can have my own Prev and Next buttons.  Doing it in swift is a plus.

Sounds simple enough, but it's not obvious.

Comment: I do not believe this is easy to achieve. The following has some discussion and code links which may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961369/how-the-default-keyboard-comes-up-when-user-taps-in-uiwebview

Comment: I figured it out.  I'll post the code here, but what I did was added some extensions to the UIViewController (although I probably could have added them to UIWebView instead), traversed the UIViews and any subviews until I found the view with the description "<UIWebFormAccessory" and used its frame to construct a new view that I added as a subview to the existing accessoryview.  I added buttons to it, and added targets and methods for each.  In my UIViewController that contains my UIWebView, I override the button target methods and pass messages to the webView javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {

    func addNewAccessoryView(oldAccessoryView:UIView)
    {
        var frame = oldAccessoryView.frame;
        var newAccessoryView = UIView(frame:frame)
        newAccessoryView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        let fn = ".HelveticaNeueInterface-Bold"
        var doneButton = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width-80,6,100,30))
        doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        doneButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: fn, size: 15)
        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAccessoryDoneAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        var prevButton = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(2,6,50,30))
        prevButton.setTitle("<", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        prevButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        prevButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: fn, size: 15)
        prevButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAccessoryPrevAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        var nextButton = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(35,6,50,30))
        nextButton.setTitle(">", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        nextButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        nextButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: fn, size: 15)
        nextButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAccessoryNextAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        newAccessoryView.addSubview(prevButton);
        newAccessoryView.addSubview(nextButton);
        newAccessoryView.addSubview(doneButton);

        oldAccessoryView.addSubview(newAccessoryView)

    }

    func traverseSubViews(vw:UIView) -> UIView
    {
        if (vw.description.hasPrefix("<UIWebFormAccessory")) {
            return vw
        }

        for(var i = 0 ; i < vw.subviews.count; i++) {
            var subview = vw.subviews[i] as UIView;
            if (subview.subviews.count > 0) {
                var subvw = self.traverseSubViews(subview)
                if (subvw.description.hasPrefix("<UIWebFormAccessory")) {
                    return subvw
                }
            }
        }
        return UIView()
    }

    func replaceKeyboardInputAccessoryView()
    {
        // locate accessory view
        let windowCount = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.count
        if (windowCount < 2) {
            return;
        }

        let tempWindow:UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[1] as UIWindow
        var accessoryView:UIView = traverseSubViews(tempWindow)
        if (accessoryView.description.hasPrefix("<UIWebFormAccessory")) {
            // Found the inputAccessoryView UIView
            if (accessoryView.subviews.count > 0) {
                self.addNewAccessoryView(accessoryView)
            }
        }
    }

    // Override these in your UIViewController
    func buttonAccessoryNextAction(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        println("Next Clicked")
    }

    func buttonAccessoryPrevAction(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        println("Prev Clicked")
    }

    func buttonAccessoryDoneAction(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        println("Done Clicked")
    }        
}
```

Then from inside your `UIViewController` setup a `Notification` when the keyboard appears.  You can do this inside of `viewDidAppear()`.

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardDidShow:"), name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil);
```

and from within your `keyboardDidShow` handler call the `replaceKeyboardInputAccessoryView` method of the `UIViewController`.

```
func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.replaceKeyboardInputAccessoryView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me which window you access with `let tempWindow:UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[1] as UIWindow`

Comment: could this solution be rejected by Apple?

Answer (score 0):

user3670534 solution works fine, but if the order of windows is changed you can use the following to get the correct window:

```
var tempWindow: UIWindow!;
for window in UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows {
    if (window.description.hasPrefix("<UITextEffectsWindow")) {
        tempWindow = window
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a gist to accomplish this:
https://gist.github.com/kgaidis/5f9a8c7063b687cc3946fad6379c1a66

It's a `UIWebView` category where all you do is change the `customInputAccessoryView` property:

```
@interface UIWebView (CustomInputAccessoryView)

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *customInputAccessoryView;

@end
```

Keep in mind, this uses private API's, so use at your own risk, but it seems like a lot of apps do similar things nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3**

I removed the built in Accessory view and then built an own view with XIB. (thanks @Rob)
This shows howto remove the built-in view:

**WebViewExtensions.swift:**

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    func removeInputAccessoryView() {
        // locate accessory view
        let windowCount = UIApplication.shared.windows.count
        if (windowCount < 2) {
            return;
        }

        let tempWindow:UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows[1] as UIWindow
        let accessoryView:UIView = traverseSubViews(vw: tempWindow)
        if (accessoryView.description.hasPrefix("<UIWebFormAccessory")) {
            // Found the inputAccessoryView UIView
            accessoryView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func traverseSubViews(vw:UIView) -> UIView
    {
        if (vw.description.hasPrefix("<UIWebFormAccessory")) {
            return vw
        }

        for i in (0  ..< vw.subviews.count) {
            let subview = vw.subviews[i] as UIView;
            if (subview.subviews.count > 0) {
                let subvw = self.traverseSubViews(vw: subview)
                if (subvw.description.hasPrefix("<UIWebFormAccessory")) {
                    return subvw
                }
            }
        }
        return UIView()
    }
}
```

**WKWebView**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in                

            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {                    
                self.removeInputAccessoryView()
            }
        }

    }
```

By using the solution above it's possible to modify this.