# How can i implement custom keyboard with UIWebview?

Tags: uiwebview, ios9, uikeyboard

I have to implement a rich text editor, For which i have to create a custom keyboard. But i don't know how can i use custom keyboard with UIWebview. I must have to use UIWebview because i have to java script also in my editor.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961369/how-the-default-keyboard-comes-up-when-user-taps-in-uiwebview)

Custom Keyboard in UIWebView He suggests to use a UITextField as a "media" when you detect keyboard coming up inside a UIWebView. Thus, you can use whatever Keyboard type you want on the UITextField. After users taps something, copy the text in UITextField the media via JavaScript ActiveDocument.